# how to convert jpegs to video with fixed fps?

Tags: video-processing, mpeg

I have a series of jpegs,I would like to pack and compress them to a Video.
I use tool mpeg streamclip, but it double the whole  play time.

If I have 300 jpegs, set fixed fps 30, I expect to get a video of 10s length . but using stream clip I get a 20s long video.

Comment: Perhaps worth trying ffmpeg (https://ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 0):

One answer is to get someone who understands programming. The programming APIs (application interfaces, the way client programs call libraries) to the lig libraries like ffmeg have ways in which frame rate can be controlled, and it's usually quite a simple matter to modify a program to produce fewer intermediate frames if you are creating a video from a list of JPEGs.

But the best answer is probably to find a tool that supports what you want to do. That's not a question to ask a programmer especially. Ask someone who knows about video editing. (It would take me about two days to write such a tool from scratch on top of my own JPEG codec and ffmpeg, so obviously I can't do it in response to this question, but that's roughly the level of work you're looking at).